# How can I remind my boss to add me to a group where I have some work to do?

Tags: management, communication

I want to remind my boss to add me to a developer's group. I already messaged him on Slack last week, but want to remind him again.

How can I ask him without bugging him? He is really a busy guy.

Comment: Send him an email... or if some other group member can add you instead of your boss should be ok, given your boss is busy.

Comment: Well if you can get to his office (i.e. you're not a remote worker) just go to his office, knock on his door and just remind him. If that fails, remind him again and say that you have to be part of the group in order to do your work. Just be very polite. If you're a remote worker simply call or leave a message. Also try emailing him.

Answer (score 1):

Tell him, via email or Slack or whatever:

*Please forgive me if I have already asked you about this, but I need access to XYZ group.  Could you do that for me?  Or point me to how I can get it done?*